# Xamarin.iOS - WebApi Connection refused

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to connect to a web api from a pcl but the connection has been refused. I can connect thourght a browser and have checked the uri is the same. This is the error message:

```
{System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000bc] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1235 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x001c2] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:213 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:827 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2 endFunction, System.Action`1 endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:552 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:580 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002af] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.6.1.9/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:363 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:580 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.6.1.9/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:274 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3051/5f11db87/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372 
  at SDLConnectMobile.Core.Helpers.HelperHttp+<PostAsync>d__6`2[T,TResult].MoveNext () [0x000ab] in C:\SpinBytes\SDL.SDLConnectMobile\SDLConnectMobile\SDLConnectMobile.Core\Helpers\HelperHttp.cs:103 }
```

Any clue?

Thank you

Comment: this is (generally) an issue on the server - see http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message

Comment: The WebApi is published on the Local ISS, so I access it using this url: http://localhost/SDLConnect.Api    I dont know if I can access the same whey from the client...

Comment: Yes, this was the thing... the emulator was getting its own localhost. Im now using the ip address. I total forgot about this before...

Comment: I can't believe i fell into this too lol Localhost is the device

Answer (score 4):

If you mean IIS you probably run your server on a windows machine and your iOS probably on a device or on a simulator on a mac. With other words on a different computer. This means, `localhost` - which always points to the computer itself - cannot work.

You must get the IP adress of your WebAPI and connect to this instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

`localhost` will map to the loopback address of the device or simulator, not the PC that is hosting it.  You need to use the FQDN or IP address in your client code.

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` points to a local address within the machine which runs `IIS`.  You can access this API in your local machine in other machines connected to the same network if it is changed to a public API.
[Here is a tutorial on assigning a public IP to an ASP. NET WEB-API project in local machine and accessing it with a device connected to the same network](http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer)

Answer (score 0):

You must change "localhost" by your ip address in your .csproj file inside in WebAPI:

In this part of the file:
[image: In this part of the file]

In this file:
[image: In this file]